# Where can I find the consentform.html of Consent SDK by Google?

Tags: android

I have installed the following library in my app:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.6'
```

And according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent#collect_consent), I should be able to modify it, but I can't find the HTML file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just create an html in assets folder & name it **consentform.html**
During compilation, your html file will be used & default one will be overridden!

Comment: This worked thanks! Just want to add that the official consentform.html can be gotten from this [repository](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-consent-sdk-android/blob/master/consent-library/src/main/assets/consentform.html).

Comment: If, like me, you didn't have an `assets` folder, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-do-i-place-the-assets-folder-in-android-studio for how to create one.

Comment: Is there a way to translate consentform.html in different languages by using some modifiers or gradle configuration?

Comment: This works great! I am interested also in different translations, i do not know if it is possible folder assets by lang or other ways to load the conserntform.html